# How to add the data from 2 or more rows to one row in postgresql

Tags: row, postgresql-9.2

I have `Postgresql 9.2` and would like to know how to group this query so that we get only one user and would like to group by app_user2group_item_ex.user_id or app_user.id so that instead of 6 rows I get 3 (one row per one user_id) and the data in columns Japan, USA and Singapore is like listed in wished results.

Could someone let me know how to do that as with Group By per app_user.id I get an information that all other columns with number in it I have to add to `Group By or Agregate`.

If I could get some information on this specific case as I am new to postgresql.

```
SELECT 
    group_ex2group_item_ex.group_ex, 
    group_ex2group_item_ex.items_id, 
    group_ex.id, 
    group_ex.name, 
    group_ex.group_id, 
    group_item_ex.id, 
    group_item_ex.name, 
    group_item_ex.group_id, 
    app_user.first_name, 
    app_user.id, 
    app_user2group_item_ex.user_id, 
    app_user2group_item_ex.group_item_id,
    (CASE WHEN group_ex."name" = 'Japan' THEN group_item_ex.name END) AS Japan,
    (CASE WHEN group_ex."name" = 'USA' THEN group_item_ex.name END) AS USA,
    (CASE WHEN group_ex."name" = 'Singapore' THEN group_item_ex.name END) AS Singapore
FROM 
    public.group_ex, 
    public.group_ex2group_item_ex, 
    public.group_item_ex, 
    public.app_user, 
    public.app_user2group_item_ex
WHERE 
    group_ex2group_item_ex.group_ex = group_ex.id AND
    group_ex2group_item_ex.items_id = group_item_ex.id AND
    group_item_ex.group_id = group_ex.group_id AND
    app_user.id = app_user2group_item_ex.user_id AND
    app_user2group_item_ex.group_item_id = group_item_ex.id;
```

Result from query:

```
group_ex    items_id    id  name    group_id    id  name    group_id    first_name  id  user_id group_item_id   Japan   USA Singapore
1   1   1   Japan   1   1   Nagoya  1   Will    1   1   1   Nagoya      
1   2   1   Japan   1   2   Kyoto   1   Novak   3   3   2   Kyoto       
2   3   2   USA 2   3   New York    2   Will    1   1   3       New York    
2   4   2   USA 2   4   Los Angeles 2   Bos 2   2   4       Los Angeles 
3   5   3   Singapore   3   5   Pudong  3   Bos 2   2   5           Pudong
3   6   3   Singapore   3   6   Center  3   Novak   3   3   6           Center
```

Wished result (did not list all the fields here as I do not need them):

```
first_name  id  user_id Japan   USA Singapore
Will    1   1   Nagoya  New York    
Novak   3   3   Kyoto       Center
Bos 2   2       Los Angeles Pudong
```

Comment: FWIW, I think you will get an answer a lot quicker with a question like this by setting up a "SqlFiddle" with a script that creates the tables and inserts some test data.  Then all people have to do is write a query that yields the results you want.  A lot of people are shy about guessing at it and posting and "answer" without being able to test it first.  Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/ (and btw, I'm in no way associated with them).  If you want to see how to use it, just google 'sqlfiddle site:"stackoverflow.com"'

Comment: Thank you will use this in future.

Comment: Just so you understand, you didn't do anything wrong here.  Perfectly acceptable question (actually better than a lot), but from what I've seen, SqlFiddle-based questions are easy for people to help with and seem to get correct answers more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with this:

SELECT
    app_user.first_name || ' ' ||app_user.last_name AS User,
    app_user.email,
    app_user.phone_number,
    app_user.user_role_id,
    app_user.active,
    app_user.username,
    app_user.id,
    max((CASE WHEN group_ex."name" = 'Japan' THEN group_item_ex.name END)) AS Japan,
    max((CASE WHEN group_ex."name" = 'USA' THEN group_item_ex.name END)) AS USA,
    max((CASE WHEN group_ex."name" = 'Singapore' THEN group_item_ex.name END)) AS Singapore,
    app_user_role.id,
    app_user_role.name
FROM
    group_ex,
    group_ex2group_item_ex,
    group_item_ex,
    app_user,
    app_user2group_item_ex,
    app_user_role
WHERE
    group_ex2group_item_ex.group_ex = group_ex.id AND
    group_ex2group_item_ex.items_id = group_item_ex.id AND
    group_item_ex.group_id = group_ex.group_id AND
    app_user.id = app_user2group_item_ex.user_id AND
    app_user2group_item_ex.group_item_id = group_item_ex.id AND
    app_user.user_role_id = app_user_role.id
group by app_user.id, app_user.first_name, app_user_role.id, app_user_role.name
order by app_user.id